# Any limitation on HTML <li>?

Tags: python, django, html

I have the following code with Python:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="container-fluid" style="background-color: lightgray">
  <nav id="spy" class="nav nav-pills navbar-stacked">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav nav">
      <li class="">
        <a href="{% url 'PHIproduct' %}" data-scroll="" class="">
            <span class="fa fa-anchor solo"><h3>Product List</h3></span>
        </a>
        <li class="">
            {% for i in loop_times_product %}
            <a href="{% url 'PHI' %}?id={{ i }}" data-scroll="" class="">
              <span class="fa fa-anchor solo" id="{{ i }}">{{ i|safe }}</span>
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
            <li class="">
              {% for i in loop_times %}
              <a href="{% url 'PHIc' %}?id={{ i }}" data-scroll="" class="">
                <span class="fa fa-anchor solo" id="{{ i }}">{{i|safe}}</span>
              </a> {% endfor %}
              <li class="">
                {% for i in loop_timesc %}
                <a href="{% url 'button' %}?id={{ i }}" data-scroll="" class="">
                  <span class="fa fa-anchor solo" id="{{ i }}">{i|safe}}</span>
                </a> {% endfor %}
              </li>
            </li>
        </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The main purpose is to add following feature:

[image]

After I apply this code, when product A is clicked, the car and motor will not show, which means this part of code is not running:

```
<li  class="">
{% for i in loop_timesc %}<a href="{% url 'button' %}?id={{ i }}" data-scroll="" class=""><span class="fa fa-anchor solo" id="{{ i }}">{{i|safe}}</span></a>
{% endfor %}
</li>
```

Is there any limitation on `li` code or am I writing the wrong code here? Can anyone help me look at this because I already spent 2 days trying to find the mistake here but have failed.

Comment: This code is not HTML.

Comment: is HTML plus python , but the python there is running well. <li> is not html code?

Comment: The {% %} looks like Django template tags, though it could be for some other template engine. But HTML doesn't have loops of its own - you either generate server-side (Django templates, PHP, etc.) or you use Javascript - typically jQuery - to do things on click events.

Comment: If there is Python in that, then you need to tag as such and say so. Otherwise you are making us guess at what you're doing.

Comment: Please also add in the rendered html

Comment: You have a little error in the `loop_timesc` loop: you should have `{{ i|safe }}` and not `{ i|safe }}`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't inspect your code in great detail, but one thing jumped out at me: you're nesting `<li>` elements directly inside each other. You can't do that; an `<li>` needs to be a direct child of an `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

Forget about Python for the moment and just look at a simple HTML example.

Invalid:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        One
        <li>
            One A
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Valid:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        One
        <ul>
            <li>
                One A
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There may be other problems in your code, but this is certainly one to fix.

Another tip: if you're working a suspected HTML issue like this where one of the problems may be that the generated HTML simply isn't valid, don't try to figure out everything from your Python template source code. Instead, do a View Source in the browser where you can see exactly what the browser sees.

In fact, you can do a Select All and Copy from the View Source window, and then paste into the [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to see if the HTML is valid. If you're generating invalid HTML, all bets are off, so that is the first thing to check.

If you treat your server code (including templates) separately from the actual downloaded HTML that the browser sees, you'll have a much easier time debugging. The server *generates* HTML code; the browser *parses and renders* the HTML code that the server generated.

Comment: the problem is still there

Comment: Did you inspect and validate your HTML using View Source in the browser and the HTML Validator?